# Toggle metrics in specific chart in Qlik sense mashup

Tags: qliksense

I want to create a chart in a Qlik Sense mashup, in which I can toggle between metrics. For example: each line below represents a country, the X-axis is a timeline, and I want to toggle between sales, website session and NPS score on the Y-axis. This toggle should only apply this line chart and not the other objects in the mashup.

Is this possible and how would I do it?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using a line chart,
once you have build it with date and country as dimension and sales as a measure,

click on add alternative under measures, and choose website session and NPS score.

[image: alternative measure]

When you exit edit mode, you can toggle between measures by clicking on the triangle next to the Y-axis label

[image: toggle measure]

this will work in a QlikSense app or in a mashup